# Replicating Tandy TRS-80 model 100 notebook computer for-profit

Tags: design-patent, expiration

Are there any patents that would prevent someone from replicating the Tandy TRS-80 model 100 notebook computer, for instance putting a raspberry pi inside of it and then selling it?

It has been over 20 years since this product was on the market.

Here is an example of someone doing something similar: http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2015/08/surfing-the-internet-from-my-trs-80-model-100/

Answer (score 2):

There is no ***patent*** protecting the process of putting hardware in another company's case and selling it, but you will almost certainly be violating someone's trademark.

Trade dress is a legal term for the visual appearance of a product or packaging that conveys the source of the product itself. You are putting (for example) Raspberry Pi hardware inside the case of a Tandy model TRS-80 with a Radio Shack label; somebody's going to have something to say about it.

Comment: what if I don't put the name RadioShack on the case,  and I merely duplicate the size,  color,  shape etc  of the original?

Comment: Trade dress is the **visual *appearance*** of a product or packaging that conveys the source of the product itself. Unfortunately, discussing Trademark law is outside the scope of this site. You might have some questions for our [Law site](http://law.stackexchange.com).